# Changing default file permissions for cmake install command

Tags: cmake

The cmake documentation tells us that the default permissions are user read write, group read and other read.

Our project has tons of CMakeLists.txt files with INSTALL commands, and we need all our installed files and directories to be group writable. Is there any way to set/change the default permissions to include group write, without adding a PERMISSIONS spec to every INSTALL command?

Comment: Which OS are you working on?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6

Answer (score 2):

I know no way for change default install permission set in CMake.
However, you may replace `install` command for append appropriate *PERMISSIONS* to its arguments. Like this:

```
function(install TYPE)
    if(TYPE STREQUAL "FILES")
        # install(FILES) command with additional PERMISSIONS option at the end
        _install(FILES ${ARGN}
           PERMISSIONS OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ GROUP_READ WORLD_READ
        )
     else()
       # Pass original arguments for other types of install() command
       _install(${TYPE} ${ARGN})
endfunction(install)
```

This can be placed in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` before any usage of install() command. Alternatively, this code can be stored in `.cmake` script, which can be included into top-level `CMakeLists.txt` with `include()` command.

Answer (score 1):

For files and explicitly installed directories there is not global setting but from CMake 3.10.0 on you can set install permissions for auto generated directories (those that are created due to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX setting or specified in DESTINATION path):

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS.html#variable:CMAKE_INSTALL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS

and for packaging:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/variable/CPACK_INSTALL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS.html#variable:CPACK_INSTALL_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS